# Get rid of type: any in method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

maybe you can help me out here.

So I would like to get rid of the any types in the descendingComparator method and replace them with the appropriate type. I'm stuck at the moment and would be grateful for any help.

```
function descendingComparator(a: any, b: any, orderBy: string) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function getComparator(order: string, orderBy: string) {
  return order === 'desc'
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}
```

How i use it:

```
{stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy)) ...}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the "appropriate type?"

Comment: a and b are the same type?

Comment: The type would depend on the type of the parameters that you pass to the function when you use it. Since you haven't shown how you use it, it's impossible to tell what the type should be.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I updated my question :)

Comment: is this homework where you're supposed to figure out what the question wants you to see, or is this real code and you're trying to get rid of the "parameter implicitly has 'any' type" error?

Comment: That didn't help. You need to show the type of values that you pass to the `descendingComparator` function.

Comment: @DaveCousineau It's an example from [link](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting) that I want to get running with typescript. I don't want to use "any".

Answer (score 2):

If this is meant to be comparing numbers, then something like this:

```js
function descendingComparator(
   a: { [x: string]: number },
   b: { [x: string]: number },
   orderBy: string
) {
...
}
```

and you can type `a` and `b` in `getComparator` similarly.

If this is meant to be comparing an unknown but consistent type then something like this:

```js
function descendingComparator<T>(
   a: { [x: string]: T },
   b: { [x: string]: T },
   orderBy: string
) {
...
}
```

and again you can type `getComparator` similarly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem then you can do something like:

```
function descendingComparator<T extends object, TOrder extends keyof T>(a: T, b: T, orderBy: TOrder) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Use like :

```
const a = {
    x: 1
};

const b = {
    x: 2
};

descendingComparator(a, b, 'x'); // works
descendingComparator(a, b, 'y'); // needs to be 'x'
```